# Parser Error Unexpected token when trying to submit an @Input value

Tags: angular, parsing

In my angular app I have a component with a template like this:

```
 <div>
    <app-component2 [input1]="value"></app-component2>
 </div>
```

and an @Input input1 in the typescript-part.

When building/running the app, I get a Parser Error saying: Unexpected token 'value' at column...
I thought that this is the way to submit the input1 value to the component2. 
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem:

My submitted value was a string, but angular tried to find it as a property of the parent component. I submitted it with [input1]='"value"' and the parsing error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The left-hand part of the data binding is the name of the child property, the right-hand part being a value or the name of the parent property.

`@Input()` sould be defined inside your child component.
In your case we should expect *input1* to be the name of the *@Input* and *value* the name of the property from the parent component.

Parent component :

```
value: any;
```

Parent template :

```
 <div>
    <app-component2 [input1]="value"></app-component2>
 </div>
```

Child component :

```
@Input() input1: any;
```

Comment: I defined the input1 in the child, but it seems to me that the parent template doesnt "know" its child and therefor doesnt know about the "token" input1 (what causes the parse error)

Comment: is 'value' the name of a property of your parent component? as you use brackets to define tha value of input1, it expects a javascript expression